# Check box android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, checkbox

I added two check box in the on create method

```
  checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
  checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
  checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this) ; 
  checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this) ;
```

the main function of the check boxes that when ischeck() a picture will be added to the mainlayout and when uncheck the picture will be removed >> I used the code bellow, the first check box is working fine the second check box when I do check it shows the pics and then they I can remove them even with uncheck ... where is the wrong in my code ??

```
   public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(checkBox1.isChecked())
{ 

    ......
    mapOverlays.add(custom); 
}
else {
    mapOverlays.remove(custom)  ;
}

if (checkBox2.isChecked())
{
    ....

    mapOverlays.add(custom2);
}
else 
{
    mapOverlays.remove(custom2)  ;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are handling second checkbox checking differently. May be the code should look like this?

```
if (checkBox2.isChecked())
{
    ...
    mapOverlays.add(custom2);
}
else
{
    mapOverlays.remove(custom2);
}
```

**Upd:** if your code looks like in the current edit, then issue is the declaring `custom2` variable in the `if` block. You are deleting not added mapOverlay, but another one declared somewhere else.

Just replace

```
if (checkBox2.isChecked())
{
    MapItemizedOverlay custom2 = ...
```

by

```
if (checkBox2.isChecked())
{
    custom2 = ...
```

**Upd2:** there is yet another issue with your `onCheckedChanged()` method. First `if-else` runs not only on checkBox1 check/uncheck but also on checkBox2 check/uncheck. Same for the second `if-else`.

Try to rewrite method:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (buttonView.equals(checkBox1)) {
        // first if-else
    } else if (buttonView.equals(checkBox2)) {
        // second if-else
    }
}
```

or even better:

```
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.checkBox1) {
        if (isChecked) { 
            ...
            mapOverlays.add(custom);
        } else {
            mapOverlays.remove(custom);
        }
    } else if (buttonView.getId() == R.id.checkBox2) {
        if (isChecked) { 
            ...
            mapOverlays.add(custom2);
        } else {
            mapOverlays.remove(custom2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeeees it worked but I faced another problem when I check both together, and then I do uncheck for the first check box the pictures are not removed ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add checkedchangelistener to checkbox 2 as well.

```
checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this) ;
```

Comment: Thanks I was forgetting that line of code but it still didn't work